# Merge Conflict in .eslintcache file

Tags: git, github, eslint, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

[Screenshot from Github repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7OXC.png)

While merging two branches there is a merge conflict arising in .eslintcache file. I am not understanding how to solve this merge conflict. Tried resolving it on the editor as well but still no use.

Answer (score 1):

The `.eslintcache` file will be regenerated by eslint, and is not intended to be versioned.

To pass the conflict, you can accept any version of the file, then delete it from your disk.

To ignore it from further commits : you can add `.eslintcache` to your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

LeGEC's answer is likely what you *should* do.

That being said, it seems like you're not familiar with merge conflicts in general. In your screenshot, what you're seeing is that the `reducer` branch and the `main` branch have made different changes to the same line and `git` cannot automatically resolve the difference. When conflicts arise, `git` will insert conflict markers e.g.

```
<<<<<<< current
foo
=======
bar
>>>>>>> incoming
```

and leave it up to the programmer to choose how to resolve the conflict. All you need to do is choose what to keep or modify between the conflict markers and then delete the conflict markers to continue the merge.

The `git` homepage also [has some decent docs on how to resolve conflicts](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#_basic_merge_conflicts).